# How to do unit testing for void functions CPPUNIT

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I am using CPPUNIT to do unit testing for my C++ program

For non-void functions , assuming the function add() exist

```
int add(int num1 , int num2)
{
  return num1+num2;
}
```

I could do unit testing like this

```
void newtestclass::add()
{
    int result = add(2,3);
    CPP_ASSERT(result == 5 ); 

}
```

I encounter problem when i try to do unit testing for non-void functions

```
void printmenu()
{
    cout<<"1) Option A"
        <<endl
        <<"2) Option B";
}
```

How do i do unit testing for such functions to ensure 100% code coverage

I also encounter problems doing unit testing for functions nested in other functions

```
void menu_select(char x)
{
    if ( x == 'a')
    {
        add();
    }
    else if ( x == 'b' )
    {
        subtract();
    }

}

void menu()
{
  char choice;
  cout<<"a) Add "
      <<endl
      <<"b) Subtract";
  cin>>choice;

  menu_select(choice);

}
```

How do i do unit testing for such functions to ensure 100% code coverage

Answer (score 5):

**First**, You may rewrite your function to avoid to call global objects (as `std::cout`)

```
void printmenu(std::ostream& stream)
{
    stream << "1) Option A" << std::endl
           << "2) Option B";
}
```

Now you may use `printmenu(std::cout);` in normal usage
and you may test it via:

```
std::stringstream ss;

printmenu(ss);
// Check that ss.str() is what you expect.
```

You may have to create Mock to call your function with 'fake' object. (Write `MyStream` if `std::stringstream`  didn't exist)

**Second**, "void function" may modify some (global) states, these states may be checked before/after the call to see if these change correctly.

**Third**, testing the *outer* function will be seen as Integration testing and not unit testing from a time.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance , what is Integration testing ??

Comment: See [Integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing). In short it is the test of the combined modules.